# RTF page number only on certain pages

Tags: c#, rtf

I want to edit a RTF file programmatically. I have a problem with the page number. The page number in the footer should not appear on every page. The page number should not appear on the first six and the last two pages. Is it possible not to display the page number in the footer on the first six and the last two pages? Is it otherwise possible to display the page number without the footer by another command at the bottom of the page?

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil Times New Roman;}}
\viewkind4\uc1\p\sl240\slmult1\f0\fs24\paperw11905\paperh11905
\margl1133\margr1133\margt1133\margb1133\footery1133{\footer\fs16\chpgn}}
```

Comment: What is your environment? What is a programming language you are using?

Comment: The Programming language is C#.

Comment: Because of _headers_ and _footers_ are RTF destinations, they applied to sections in a RTF document. This means in order to make different footers for different parts the document should be separated to different sections and each section should have specific footer. Therefore it's more easy to create document with required page numeration than make changes with already created document.